# Wordpress "white screen of death" unique issue, never seen before

Tags: wordpress, error-handling

I am trying to figure out why I am getting a white screen/blank page... I first experienced this when editing a page. After I hit update, the post.php page went blank. When I tried to access the site (top level) it was a blank white page. When I went home, to a new network, the site worked just fine. So I began editing the pages again. I hit update again, and got the white page again. Can't see the front end of the site either. If I access the site from my phone, not using wifi, I can see the site. But here is the kicker... If I try to access ANY Wordpress site on my server, I get a blank white screen. I've searched and can't find anyone who has experienced this? Any help or direction is much appreciated. This is a new VPS server from HostGator. I have contacted HostGator but so far they haven't been able to replicate it.

Comment: Check your logs. An error is occurring somewhere. Check the logs to find out where.

Answer (score 0):

White screens are PHP errors. Try Debug and see what PHP errors you are getting.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Add

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`

in wp-config.php and the debug.log file will be in wp-content.

Add this line

`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

to wp-config.php to log *and* dump them to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a conflicting plugin  - Yoast SEO - I disabled it and it stopped the error.

It occurred whenever I tried to update a post as an admin user.